# SSMS 18 Incorrect syntax near '<', expecting ID or QUOTED_ID

Tags: ssms

I'm just trying to use T-SQL to create a new user for my database.

create user  for login

However, there is an unfixable error which is Incorrect syntax near '<', expecting ID or QUOTED_ID.

I'm using AzureDB, so I can't use the query editor to fix it. Is there any other way to add a user as i'm running SSMS 18.

Comment: can you please post he query?

Comment: @Prakash CREATE USER <user-name> for login <login-name>   the error occurs at the <user-name> portion